# Subscription does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.Graph

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following the tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/5-exercise-change-notifications

But I'm getting this error:

The type or namespace name 'Subscription' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Graph' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Anyone can point what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can happen in case you are using NuGet `Microsoft.Graph` v5. There are [breaking changes](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md) between v4 and v5.

Check the version of the `Microsoft.Graph` packages and try to downgrade to the latest version `4.54.0`.

Otherwise you need to rewrite the code for v5 and it can be quite challenge because there will more issues.

Answer (score 0):

Found this tidbit in https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md

> Model types are now in the
> Microsoft.Graph.Models/Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models namespaces.

So `Microsoft.Graph.Subscription` just needs to be renamed `Microsoft.Graph.Models.Subscription` or use a `using Microsoft.Graph.Models;`.